# Create HTML page with two submit buttons

Tags: html

I have the next HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE><html><body>
<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='uploadFile'/>
<input type='submit' /></form>
</body></html>
```

Which create a file input and `submit` button, which sends a POST method (`/upload`).

I want to create a new button (`submitBig`), which would send another POST method (`/uploadBig`).

How can I do it?

Comment: @jumpingcode: No, the input file need to be the same

Comment: Otherwise, use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround, Create 2 Forms:

```
<!DOCTYPE><html><body>

<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='uploadFile'/>
<input type='submit' /></form>

<form method='post' action='/uploadBig' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='uploadFileBig'/>
<input type='submit' /></form>

</body></html>
```

Else you should indeed refer to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to run a different function for each button.  Set the .action and do the .submit from there.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Javascript. Essentially this will edit the `Action` of the `form` and post it on click:

```
$('#big-submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest('form').attr('action', '/uploadBig').submit();
});
```

An even better solution would be to just have the one button, and then get the file size on click and post to the relevant action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery or simple Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" id="theForm" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
            <input type="submit" value="normal Submit (/upload)" />
            <input type="button" id="bigButton" value="big Submit (/uploadBig)" />
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');

            /* When the button is clicked */
            document.getElementById('bigButton').onclick = function() {
                /* Change the location */
                theForm.action = '/uploadBig';

                /* Submit the form */
                theForm.submit();
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 `formaction` attribute to do that (but you have to check it's compatibility with your requirements to use it : it only works on recent browsers).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit big" formaction="/uploadBig" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here One way to get around this is to handle each button's OnClick event and set the "action" for the form dynamically:

```
<!-- create the form -->
<form name="Form1" method="post">

<!-- Add the data entry bits -->
Your Name <input type="text" name="text1" size="10" /><br />

<!-- Add some buttons -->
<INPUT type="button" value="Button1" name=button1 onclick="return OnButton1();">
<INPUT type="button" value="Button2" name=button2 onclick="return OnButton2();">

<!-- close the form -->
</form>
```

Our button click handlers for Button1 and Button2 would look like the following:

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "Page1.aspx"
    document.Form1.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.Form1.action = "Page2.aspx"
    document.Form1.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}
-->
</script>
<noscript>You need Javascript enabled for this to work</noscript>
```

Where Page1.aspx should be called when Button1 is pressed, and Page2.aspx called when Button2 is pressed.